# Centered axes in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to draw a scatter plot, and I want to display both axes in the centre of the plot kind of like this:

[image]

However Highcharts displays axis like this ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9cgcnmwm/2/)):

[image]

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title:{
            text:''
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "x"
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            min: -5,
            max: 5,
            tickInterval: 1,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "y"
            },
            min: -5,
            max: 5,
            tickInterval: 1,
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            type: "line",
             marker: {
                 enabled: false
             },

            data: [
                [-3, 3],
                [-2, 2],
                [-1, 1],
                [0, 0],
                [1, 1],
                [2, 2],
                [3, 3]

            ]
        }]

    });
});
```

Highcharts does have a way to manually offset the axes as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/offset-centered/), but that requires manually calculating the size of the chart and offsetting the axis by the right number of pixels (in other words - a massive hack)

Is there any proper way to have centered axes in Highcharts?

Comment: Check the answers here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330775/highcharts-make-the-x-and-y-axes-intersect-at-0

Answer (score 3):

You can use plugin to achieve that. See [`Crossing Specific Values`](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jsCJF/